# Freebase: how to get more than 10 items in a property values list?

Tags: google-api, freebase

For example when I query :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/060d2?filter=/government/government_office_or_title/office_holders
```

to get the list of the US presidents, *count* says 44 but *values* only has 10 items.
How can I get all the presidents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found how. It is as easy as adding a *limit* parameter to the URL. For example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/060d2?filter=/government/government_office_or_title/office_holders&limit=50
```